# How to convert MongoDB storage engine from wiredTiger to In-Memory in replica set?

Tags: mongodb, in-memory, replicaset, wiredtiger

I have 3 node mongoDB replica set using wiredTiger. I want to use In-Memory engine.So two node will be using in-memory(one of them will be primary) and 3rd will be using WT(using as arbiter). Is it possible to convert storage engine for two of the nodes from WT to in-memory? if yes can please share some resources to follow. Also if there are any best practice for in-memory mongoDB replica set?

Thanks

Comment: Remember that an [arbiter does not store data](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-arbiter/), so if your first 2 nodes are using the in-memory storage engine, the WiredTiger node can *not* be an arbiter.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [mongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/#replica-set), your configuration for a replica set is fine and you'll have to follow some rules:

- The instance running with WiredTiger should be hidden
- It's priority should be set at 0 (This is [optionnal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].priority) if you set the property `arbiterOnly: true`)

To set an instance to inMemory mode from the command line:

`mongod --storageEngine inMemory --dbpath <path>`

Or, if using the YAML configuration file format:

```
storage:
   engine: inMemory
   dbPath: <path>
```

Comment: Thanks @Paradise228. Would `mongod --storageEngine inMemory --dbpath <path>` this overwrite the existing wiredTiger storage engine?

Comment: yes, you can see the result by running `db.serverStatus().storageEngine` in the mongo shell